Intellij wizard to create new Project from an existing Poetry project is incorrect
When I create a new Python project using poetry and then try to open it in Intellij the wizard is wildly wrong.  Here are the steps and the problems with the wizard.  In the bash shell:
$ poetry new 2_0
$ cd 2_0
$ poetry env use /usr/bin/python3.12
Creating virtualenv 2-0-8FFCH961-py3.12 in /home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Using virtualenv: /home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/2-0-8FFCH961-py3.12

In Intellij:
New -> Project From Existing Sources 
Select the 2_0 directory that Poetry created
Create project from existing sources
Project name: accept default. Next
Source files for your project have been found. ...  Accept default.  Next
Please select project sdk:


The list of project sdks does not include the virtual env just created.  There is no way to refresh this list.
Click + to Add sdk
Add Python SDK -> Poetry Environment -> Existing Environment.


It takes me to the project directory, which is incorrect.  I have to navigate to where my new virtual env was created (and all existing virtual envs are)

I select the python binary and click OK

It adds the sdk, but with the wrong name.
I correct the name and Click Next.
Is there a better way to open a Poetry project in Intellij?  The wizard that Intellij provides is very badly done.
I've also noticed that the PyCharm forum is pretty dead.  None of the tickets are getting comments.

Thank you for reporting this problem.
We've successfully reproduced it and updated the related YouTrack thread. Once the issue is in progress, you will receive updates regarding its status. Please do not hesitate to update the issue if anything needs to be added.
